# How to change pagination url in cakephp for better seo

Tags: php, cakephp, seo, pagination, paging

When I use CakePHP Pagination I get the default url like this:

```
localhos/posts/index/page:3/sort:title/direction:asc
```

But What do I have to change in the controller, the view and the routes.php to create a working url like this:

```
localhost/posts/page/3/sort/title/direction/asc
```

or

```
localhost/posts/page/3/title/asc
```

Comment: You'll want to read about [Cake's routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) and how it ties into the pagination component.  You will use mod_rewrite in the solution.  I did this once with cake but thinking back now all I get is a blinding pain in my head.  Cake.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'paramType' => 'querystring'
);
```

More details about this [[here]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#pagination-with-get-parameters)

It makes it so instead of:

```
/posts/index/page:3/sort:title/direction:asc
```

It's:

```
/posts/index?page=3&sort=title&direction=asc
```

IMO this is the best way to go for SEO and everything else.  Unless you're the very rare case that wants to optimize for keywords like "asc", "3", "direction", "title", using query string parameters like this are ideal.

Comment: I see in this link http://www.sakic.net/blog/changing-cakephp-pagination-urls/ is approach my question, but I was confused to add page/ behind number, had to add extra route configuration.Any Idea ?